# Poincaré inequality and Lax-Milgram lemma on a convex space

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

Consider the Hilbert space $H_0^1(\mathbb R^n)$ defined as the closure of $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ in $H^1(\mathbb R^n)$. I am interested in the following convex subspace:
$$\mathscr C \,:= \left\{\,u\in H_0^1(\mathbb R^n) \ \Bigg|\ u\geq0\,,\, \int_{\mathbb R^n} u(x)\,dx=1 \,\right\} \,.$$

**Part 1**

In general Poincaré inequality does not hold on $H_0^1(\mathbb R^n)$. However is it possible to state it on $\mathscr C$? To be precise, is there a constant $c<\infty$ such that
$$ ||u||_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)} \,\leq c\,||\nabla u||_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)} \quad \forall\,u\in\mathscr C \quad?$$

**Part 2**

Is it possible to state a Lax-Milgram theorem for the space $\mathscr C$ ? Something like the following. Let $A(\cdot,\cdot)$ and $L(\cdot)$ be respectively a bilinear and linear form on $H_0^1(\mathbb R^n)$, such that

- A is bounded on $H_0^1(\mathbb R^n)\,$: there exists $C$ such that $A(u,v)\leq C\,||u||_{H_0^1(\mathbb R^n)}\,||v||_{H_0^1(\mathbb R^n)}\,$ for all $u,v\in H_0^1(\mathbb R^n)$
- A is coercive on $\mathscr C\,$: there exists $C$ such that $A(u,u)\geq C\,||u||_{H_0^1(\mathbb R^n)}\,$ for all $u\in\mathscr C$
- L is bounded on $H_0^1(\mathbb R^n)\,$: there exists $C$ such that $L(u)\leq C\,||u||_{H_0^1(\mathbb R^n)}\,$ for all $u\in H_0^1(\mathbb R^n)$

Then given $v\in H_0^1(\mathbb R^n)$ (or possibly in $\mathscr C$), is there a unique solution $u\in\mathscr C$ to the equation
$$A(u,v) = L(v) \quad?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1 is not true. Take $n=1$, and define $u_k$ to be continuous with $u_k=\frac1{k+1}$ on $[0,k]$, $u=0$ outside of $[-1,k+1]$, affine linear on $[-1,0]$ and $[k,k+1]$. So these functions are piecewise linear bumps with support growing wider for growing $k$.

If I am not mistaken $\int u_k=1$, $\|u_k\|_{L^2}^2 \sim \frac1k$, $\|\nabla u_k\|_{L^2}^2 \sim \frac1{k^2}$, so that
$$
\frac{ \|\nabla u_k\|_{L^2} }{\|u_k\|_{L^2} }\to 0.
$$

Part 2 can also be answered in the negative. Define $L$ by $Lv=\int lv$ for some negative $l$ with $supp\ l = \mathbb R^n$. Then there cannot be a solution of the problem in $C$ if $A$ equals the $H^1$-inner product.

If one formulates the problem as variational inequality:  Find $u\in C$ such that
$$
A(u,v-u) \ge L(v-u) \quad \forall v\in C,
$$
then this is always uniquely solvable. The corresponding theorem reduces to Lax-Milgram if $C=H^1$.

Comment: Thank you! I wait before accepting the answer to see if somebody has any insight about part 2